# GAMM with zero-inflated data

Tags: poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model, zero-inflation

Is it possible to fit a GAMM(Generalized Additive Mixed Model) for zero-inflated data in R?

If not, is it possible to fit a GAM(Generalized Additive Model) for zero-inflated data with a negative binomial or quasi Poisson distribution in R? (I found *COZIGAM::zigam* and *mgcv:ziP* functions for Poisson distribution)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to **mgcv** and its zero-inflated Poisson families (`ziP()` and `ziplss()`), you might also look at the **brms** package by Paul-Christian Bürkner. It can fit distribution models (where you model more than just the mean, in your case the zero-inflation component of the model can be modelled as a function of covariates just like the count function).

You can include smooths in any of the linear predictors (for the mean/count, zero-inflation part, etc) via `s()` and `t2()` terms for simple 1-d or isotropic 2-d splines, or anisotropic tensor product splines respectively. It has support for zero-inflated binomial, Poisson, negative binomial, and beta distributions, plus zero-one-inflated beta distributions. It also has hurdle models for Poisson and negative binomial responses (where the count part of the model is a truncated distribution so as to not produce further zero counts).

**brms** fits these models using **STAN**, so they are fully Bayesian, but this will require you to learn a new set of interfaces to extract relevant information. That said, there are several packages offering support functions for just this task, and **brms** has helper functions written that utilise these secondary packages. You'll need to get STAN installed and you'll need a C++ compiler as **brms** compiles the model as defined using R into STAN code for evalutation.

Answer (score 5):

The `glmmTMB` package offers this and is described in a recent bioRxiv paper: Brooks et al. (2017). *Modeling Zero-Inflated Count Data with `glmmTMB`*, bioRxiv, [doi:10.1101/132753](http://doi.org/10.1101/132753).

Gavin Simpson also has a nice blog post that compares `glmmTMB` with `mgcv` for this purpose: [Fitting count and zero-inflated count GLMMs with mgcv](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/05/04/compare-mgcv-with-glmmTMB/).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link to my blog post. That was a fun, distracting afternoon playing with new pkgs.

Comment: Thanks also for pointing to `brms` which indeed is very nice and flexible. Together with Niki Umlauf I have also been planning to write some count families for `bamlss` to get some further flexible regression features... but so far we didn't get round to count data distributions.