# GAMM with Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial - Looking for a package in R

Tags: mixed-model, negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model, zero-inflation, gamm4

I am looking for an R package to fit *Generalized Additive Mixed Models* (GAMMs) with **ZINB** distribution.

**ZINB** is not available in the `mgcv` package nor in the `gamm4` package. I read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/295998/gamm-with-zero-inflated-data) that it might be possible with the `brms` package, but I have never worked in a Bayesian framework.

Do you know any other frequentist package that would allow fitting a `GAMM` with **ZINB**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This model is possible with the brms R package which is an interface to R:

A slight modification of one of the examples from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_distreg.html shows essentially what is involved in setting up and fitting the model

```
## load package
library('brms')
## load data
zinb <- read.csv("http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/fish.csv")

## fit a model with constant zero inflation
fit_zinb1 <- brm(count ~ s(persons, k = 4) + s(child, k = 4) + camper, 
                 data = zinb, family = zero_inflated_negbinomial(),
                 chains = 4, cores = 4,
                 control = list(adapt_delta = 0.999))
## plot the marginal effects
plot(marginal_effects(fit_zinb1))
## model summary
summary(fit_zinb1, WAIC = FALSE)

## fit a model where the zero-inflation is a constant plus a linear
##   effect of number of children
fit_zinb2 <- brm(bf(count ~ s(persons, k = 4) + s(child, k= 4) + camper,
                    zi ~ s(child, k = 4)), 
                 data = zinb, family = zero_inflated_negbinomial(),
                 chains = 4, cores = 4,
                 control = list(adapt_delta = 0.999))
## plot the marginal effects
plot(marginal_effects(fit_zinb2))
## model summary
summary(fit_zinb2, WAIC = FALSE)
```

There's more to this that shown above (you need to do some amount of model checking, look at posterior predictive checks etc) but it gives you an idea of what's involved in fitting a GAM --- you'll need to look at the help for **brms** to find the syntax for random effects.

The other alternative is to use the **gamlss** package, which has the ZINBI family for zero-inflated NegBin and as with **brms** you can model all of the parameters of the distribution with linear predictors.

Comment: Is this still up-to-date as of 2023?

Comment: I would probably add the bamlss package now, as I’m pretty sure that can do these things. But I’d have to check and I haven’t done a survey of the packages in a while.